# Node.js Passport Authentification through Apache-Redirect Proxy

Tags: node.js, apache, redirect, proxy, passport.js

I'm  building a node.js application with an integrated passport-account system. Since I'm hosted on uberspace.de, I need to configure my .htaccess in the main web-root like so:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://localhost:34457/$1 [P]
```

My express-route for login is: (Accessible at `/api/auth/login`)

```
router.post('/login', passport.authenticate('login', { 
    successRedirect: '/account',
    failureRedirect: '/login?error=true'
}));
```

As how I understand Passport, if a successful login was performed, I should be redirected to `/account` and if not, to `/login?error=true`.

But if I perform a POST by using

```
url --data "email=foo@bar.com&password=test" http://[domain]/api/auth/login
```

the result is:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>502 Proxy Error</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Proxy Error</h1>
<p>The proxy server received an invalid
response from an upstream server.<br />
The proxy server could not handle the request <em><a href="/api/auth/login">POST&nbsp;/api/auth/login</a></em>.<p>
Reason: <strong>Error reading from remote server</strong></p></p>
<hr>
<address>Apache/2.2.15 (CentOS) Server at [domain] Port 80</address>
</body></html>
```

And if I execute the same query by a html-form (Method: POST, Action: `/api/auth/login`) in Chrome, I get redirected to `/api/auth/login%5E` (which obivously returns a `404`).

Simple redirects like this one work:

```
router.post('/redirectToHome', function(req, res, next) {
    res.redirect(302, '/'); 
});
```

But even if I perform this function when calling `/api/auth/login`

```
router.post('/login', function(req, res, next) {
    passport.authenticate('login', function(err, user, info) {
        if (err) return next(err);  
        if (!user) {
            console.log(info);
            return res.json(401, {success: false});
        } else {
            console.log(info);
            return res.json(200, {success: true});
        }
    })(req, res, next); 
});
```

I will still get redirected to `/api/auth/login%5E`.

My authentification-strategy for `login` is implemented as:

```
var LocalStrategy   = require('passport-local').Strategy;
var User = require('../models/user');
var bCrypt = require('bcrypt-nodejs');

module.exports = function(passport){

    passport.use('login', new LocalStrategy({
            usernameField: 'email',
            passReqToCallback : true
        }, function(req, email, password, done) { 
            // check in mongo if a user with username exists or not
            User.findOne({ 'email' :  email }, 
                function(err, user) {
                    // In case of any error, return using the done method
                    if (err)
                        return done(err);
                    // Username does not exist, log the error and redirect back
                    if (!user){
                        console.log('User Not Found with email '+email);
                        return done(null, false, req.flash('message', 'User Not found.'));                 
                    }
                    // User exists but wrong password, log the error 
                    if (!isValidPassword(user, password)){
                        console.log('Invalid Password');
                        return done(null, false, req.flash('message', 'Invalid Password')); // redirect back to login page
                    }
                    // User and password both match, return user from done method 
                    // which will be treated like success
                    return done(null, user);
                });
            }));
    var isValidPassword = function(user, password){
        return bCrypt.compareSync(password, user.password);
    }
}
```

Even if the `login`-router is written as follows:

```
router.post('/login', function(req, res, next) {
    passport.authenticate('login', function(err, user, info) {
        if (err) return next(err);  
        if (!user) {
            console.log(info);
            return res.json(401, {success: false});
        } else {
            console.log(info);
            return res.json(200, {success: true});
        }
    })(req, res, next); 
});
```

I still get redirected to `/api/auth/login%5E`.

My passport `login`-strategy is implemented like so:

```
var LocalStrategy   = require('passport-local').Strategy;
var User = require('../models/user');
var bCrypt = require('bcrypt-nodejs');

module.exports = function(passport){

    passport.use('login', new LocalStrategy({
            usernameField: 'email',
            passReqToCallback : true
        }, function(req, email, password, done) { 
            // check in mongo if a user with username exists or not
            User.findOne({ 'email' :  email }, 
                function(err, user) {
                    // In case of any error, return using the done method
                    if (err)
                        return done(err);
                    // Username does not exist, log the error and redirect back
                    if (!user){
                        console.log('User Not Found with email '+email);
                        return done(null, false, req.flash('message', 'User Not found.'));                 
                    }
                    // User exists but wrong password, log the error 
                    if (!isValidPassword(user, password)){
                        console.log('Invalid Password');
                        return done(null, false, req.flash('message', 'Invalid Password')); // redirect back to login page
                    }
                    // User and password both match, return user from done method
                    // which will be treated like success
                    return done(null, user);
                });
            }));
    var isValidPassword = function(user, password){
        return bCrypt.compareSync(password, user.password);
    }
}
```

What is the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, my problem was some invisible character, that redirected me to some other page, which then made a bunch of other things go wrong.